# Make a new line in substring (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, substring, newline

I am trying to replace a substring with new line within it.

My code:
`str = str.split('testtest').join('test\ntest')`

My string:
`test,test,testtest,test,testtest,test,test`

How it suppose to look after the code line is called:

```
test,test,test
test,test,test
test,test,test
```

How it actually looks after it's called
`test,test,testtest,test,testtest,test,test`

Comment: Where are you outputting this result? If you log it you get the desired result, if you use it as HTML then the newlines will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to put this result in a html element, simplest is to use `innerText` and not `innerHTML`.

`innerText` will preserve the newlines, while `innerHTML` doesnt.

```js
var str = "test,test,testtest,test,testtest,test,test"

str = str.split("testtest").join("test\ntest");

document.getElementById("result").innerText = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Way 1: [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag dont trim \n sympols:

```js
const str = 'test,test,testtest,test,testtest,test,test'
  .split('testtest').join('test\ntest');
pre.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<pre id=pre></pre>
```

Way 2: [br](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

```js
const str = 'test,test,testtest,test,testtest,test,test'
  .split('testtest').join('test<br/>test');
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about how you're outputting it. If you're outputting it to the console, then the new lines will work as expected. If you're trying to output it to HTML, then you need to be using `<br />` instead of `\n` or even wrapping it in a `<pre>` tag, like another answer has suggested. To format it for markup, I would do this:

```js
let str = "test,test,testtest,test,testtest,test,test";
str = str.split('testtest').join('test<br />test');
```